# How can electron have known momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In many exercises it is given that electron has a know speed, e.g. 5*10^3 m/s. But how is this possible when we deal with Heisenberg principle?

Comment: Did you calculate the position uncertainty given that (low) velocity?

Answer (score 5):

The Heisenberg uncertainty principle places limits on the precision with which you can know pairs of particular properties, two of which are position and momentum. We can know an electron's momentum (and hence speed) arbitrarily well, at the cost of knowing next-to-nothing about its position. It's not that we can't determine the speed of an object, it's that there are limits on how precisely we can determine it. That also does not imply that the electron does not have a true velocity, it's just that nature hasn't given us the tools to quantify all properties of the electron simultaneously. It's not unreasonable to have that true velocity as a given in any calculation.